# Set camera ios phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, canvas, camera

I'm having a couple of issues I tell them. I am taking a picture with the plugin Camera with phonegap and that suits me, what I do with that image is about putting another picture above I'm doing it through canvas and the problem is this left images to make it look. Zoom or something applied.

Original image

https://scontent-mia.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10987455_403839709795958_6331116352644016645_n.jpg?oh=df8fc2cef2c1255a6babec94b3a2056d&oe=557E3520

Canvas image

https://scontent-mia.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/11064814_403839689795960_2255378534429169909_n.jpg?oh=9c0ebab7c6e9911cc28695fa80cc3033&oe=5581D16B

Also, when I take photos I can not take it whole, something I do not understand that there will be cutting the image.

Here's the setup method camera and canvas.

```
$scope.guardarFoto = function(){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("img_foto");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img_foto2");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0);
window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    document.getElementById('myCanvas')
   );
  }


 Camera.DestinationType = {
DATA_URL : 0,      // Return image as base64-encoded string
FILE_URI : 1,      // Return image file URI
NATIVE_URI : 2     // Return image native URI (e.g., assets-library:// on iOS or content:// on Android)
 };

 Camera.PictureSourceType = {
PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
CAMERA : 1,
SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
 };

 Camera.EncodingType = {
JPEG : 0,               // Return JPEG encoded image
PNG : 1                 // Return PNG encoded image
 };

 Camera.MediaType = {
PICTURE: 0,    // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
VIDEO: 1,      // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
ALLMEDIA : 2 
 };

 Camera.Direction = {
BACK : 0,      // Use the back-facing camera
FRONT : 1      // Use the front-facing camera
 };

 $scope.getPhoto = function() {
var options = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 500,
  targetHeight: 500,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
  console.log(imageURI);
  $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
}, function(err) {
  // error
  });
};
```

Comment: Did you try to modify targetWidth/targetHeight of camera-plugin-options and assigning window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight instead of 500/500? Or as I measured your canvas-image instead of 400/400.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but not working.